# ArrayList. Access to name by article by product type

Tags: java, list, sorting, enums, arraylist

My Arraylist contains 9 persons. Each person has a name value of type String, an age value of type int and a value of type Enum (TV, SMARTPHONE, CAR). I must create implement a method that will  find the name according to the product name. 
If arrayListName contains SMARTPHONE, return all names with a smartphone.

```
public void showByProduct(Product SMARTPHONE) {



    public void showByProductName(Product SMARTPHONE) {

            if (arrayListName.contains(SMARTPHONE))

                System.out.println("found"+nameofowner);
            else {
                System.out.println("not found");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Could you please paste your effort please.. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to iterate over your `List`, and for each Person, check if it's `product` field has the value of the one that you passed in the method.

Additionally, you would need to have one more `List` local to your method, in which you would add the `Person` which matches the `Product Name`, and then at the end return that `List`.

```
public List<Person> showByProductName(Product product) {

    List<Person> localList = new ArrayList<Person>();

    for (Person person: persons) {   // persons is the original List.
        if (person.getProduct() == product) {
            localList.add(person);
        }
    }

    return localList;
}
```

And the place where you call this method, store the return value in a `List` reference: -

```
List<Person> result = showByProductName(Product.SMARTPHONE);
System.out.println(result);
```

Note that, you can compare two `enum` values using `==`. As an `enum` is a `singleton`.

**P.S: -** Don't have your parameter name as `SMARTPHONE`. It's an enum value. And also as per *Java Naming Convention*, variables name should start with lowercase alphabets, and follow `camelCasing` thereon.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (Person p : arrayListName){
    if(p.geProduct()==product)
        System.out.println("Found : " + p.name());
}
```

This is not really cool however. I think you should sort your persons with the Enum.